# Get full path in fileupload control - web

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I want to get full path to the file but I only get the file name on Firefox and Chrome but on IE I get the full name of the file. Is there anyway I can get similar functionality on browsers other than IE?

I don't want to upload the file to the server but only need the full path to the file and store it. Is there any other way to achieve similar functionality ?

I did find on internet that it is not allowed to get the full path due to security but IE is showing it somehow.

**IE:**

[image: IE Image]

**FF**

[image: FF Image]

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome Image]

**Result in console**

**IE**

[image: Result IE]

**FF**

[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your sample code ?

Comment: @KamalaHB updated question

Answer (score 0):

If you use the standard html file element you will need to accept what they display and these will be inconsistent across browsers.

Since you are using jQuery, it might be worth exploring some available upload component that will show consistently and might have an API that exposes the file paths that you can use for saving? for example: https://www.plupload.com/examples/core